# Create a new relationship if any relationship exists in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How do I create a new relationship if any relationship exists?
In other words, how do I duplicate all relationships under a new type?

For example, starting with following data:

`(A)-[knows]-(B)-[lives]-(house1)-[belongs_to]-(C)`

I want to have added following relationships:

`(A)-[some_rel]-(B)-[some_rel]-(house1)-[some_rel]-(C)`

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Sorry, brain fried, it was way easier than I confused myself into

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`match (a)-[r]->(b) with a,b merge (a)-[:some_rel]->(b)`

Answer (score 0):

To "duplicate all relationships" (*including* their properties), you can do this:

```
MATCH (a)-[r1]->(b)
CREATE (a)-[r2:some_rel]->(b)
SET r2 = r1
```

The `CREATE` clause would even duplicate existing `some_rel` relationships. If you want to avoid that, then you can use `MERGE` instead.